# How to separate js bundle to frameworkBundle and appBundle

Tags: react-native

js bundle is more 500k+, but business code is less then 10%;
so I want to separate  bundle to FrameworkBundle and AppBundle;

But I found modify the package code has some difficult
(local-cli/bundle/output/bundel.js)
(packager/react-packager/src/Serer/index.js  socket work how to debug or print log ?)

Does anyone have an idea ?